# Using flash to search for a XML element value. (a simple search function)

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm having some problems getting a flash application (in AS3) to search for a specific element value inside a xml. I have the following xml file.

```
 <clientlist>
  <pessoa>
    <id>0140</id>
    <nome>Maria Manuela</nome>
    <email>mariamanuela@gmail.com</email>
    <contacto>969876543</contacto>
  </pessoa>
  <pessoa>
    <id>0141</id>
    <nome>Maria Jose</nome>
    <email/>
    <contacto>961234567</contacto>
  </pessoa>
  <pessoa>
<clientlist>
```

I have a "search" field where, supposedly, I would type a name and would get an array of "pessoa"s, but I am having some problems making the loop happen.

So, imagine I would search for "Maria", I wanted to get a:

trace(PessoaArray[0]) =

```
<id>0140</id>
<nome>Maria Manuela</nome>
<email>mariamanuela@gmail.com</email>
<contacto>967060255</contacto>
```

trace(PessoaArray[1]) =

```
<id>0141</id>
<nome>Maria Jose</nome>
<email/>
<contacto>968496127</contacto>
```

Can anyone help me out? I'm not new to flash AS3 (even though i'm not exactly a pro), but its my first time messing with XML files.

Thank you.

Marco Roberto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the short answer:  `xmlData.*.(nome == $name))`

the long answer...

tested this in a FLA with a textfield`_tf` and button`_btn`

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var $data:XML = <clientlist>
  <pessoa>
    <id>0140</id>
    <nome>Maria Manuela</nome>
    <email>mariamanuela@gmail.com</email>
    <contacto>969876543</contacto>
  </pessoa>
  <pessoa>
    <id>0141</id>
    <nome>Maria Jose</nome>
    <email/>
    <contacto>961234567</contacto>
  </pessoa>
</clientlist>;

_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);

function onClick($e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace($data.*.(nome == _tf.text))

}
```

Comment: I know some people like to use a dollar sign as a prefix for function parameters in as3 applications, but $data?

Comment: yah, `$data` is bit much. I've been using the $ before the var name within functions, makes it easy(for me) to figure out the the scope of the variable. but this was a quick example I threw together, so I didn't pay much attention to it. Maybe with enough downvotes I'll fix it.

Comment: `$prefix` is forgivable, `_prefix` is ugly but common, but all is well as long as people avoid using the horrendous, burn-my-eyes-out double underscore:  `__killMe`.  omg.  that's the WORST.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I actually use `_prefix` but I can admit it doesn't look pleasant, at the very least we can all agree that `__prefix` is an abomination to mankind that should be killed with fire.

Comment: @Daniel I wasn't saying `$data` was wrong or anything, I just thought it was a little odd since I don't see it that much(well at all really) in as3 code. Other than that your answer is perfectly legit and correct. +1